# На эмуляторе в android studio, картинка становится мутной

Tags: android, android-studio

Вот что показано до запуска эмулятора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это после запуска, на самом эмуляторе. Почему-то размыта. Не могу понять почему так. Помогите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
`<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:src="@drawable/android_picture"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/grey"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/edit_profile_btn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>`
```

Comment: Приложите к вопросу код, в котором идёт настройка изображения.

Comment: На первом скрине имеется код изображения, CircleImageView. Или же вам нужно, чтобы его можно было скопировать, для удобства проверки?

Comment: Никто не будет рассматривать скриншот в поисках кода. Для это есть возможность приложить к вопросу текст, который будет содержать код, воспроизводящий проблему. Подробнее читайте о том, **[как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** и **[как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Понял. Добавил.

Comment: это векторное изображение или растровое? в какой именно папке ресурсов (какие у нее квалификторы) оно находится и какая плотность экрана эмулируемого устройства, если оно растровое? какая версия android эмулируется?

Comment: Это изображение - растровое. Изображение находится: app/res/drawable/android_picture.png. Плотность 420dpi, модель pixel(Пробовал запускать и на других, все так же). Версия: android oreo (8.1), API level 27.

Comment: Зачем у layout_width и layout_height размер в 0dp?